# Admob mediation ads not showing

Tags: android, admob, millennial-media

I am trying to use AdMob Mediation to show millennial media(MMedia) ads. I have downloaded the MMediaSDK and MMediaadmob adapter (MillennialMediaMediationGoogle5.1.jar which i am not referencing anywhere so I don't know what the point is). And I declared the MMActivity in my manifest xml.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
```

And then I added the mmedia ad unit ID in the mediation page in AdMob.

The problem is I havnt had a single ad from mmedia and my app is Active on mmedia because I requested some test ads while developing.

I also played around with the ecpm requirements in admob mediation but for a week I still havnt got a single ad from mmedia.

I think i am missing somehting min my code.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the AdUnitId for your (Admob) AdView is your mediation id then your code should be fine.

Is Millennial above Admob in your mediation config? Admob has a very high fill rate (often 100%), so if it is first MillennialMedia may never get called.

Comment: What do you mean "if it is first"? how do I change it to second?

Comment: When looking at your mediation list in the Admob dashboard, go into EditMediation for you AdUnit. You will see all of the networks you are using and each has an eCPM value. They are ordered from highest eCPM value down and that is the order they are called in. So make sure that your MillennialMedia eCPM is greater than that for Admob.